# Blenderkit shows only few models

Tags: blender

I just downloaded Blenderkit and have been playing around with it. What I found is that it shows only few assets. Especially, there are only 3 pages in model section. Here is the clip I took a shot:

[Blenderkit issue](https://youtu.be/BkUFf5ra_aE)

How do I find more assets?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that due to networking problems the search was interrupted. And so it shows only few pages of results and nothing more. You can try to search again, it should load properly. Just hit enter in search field and the search will run again.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I've tried it many times, but the result is the same. I have no clue.